# Moodle Course ID always equals to 1

Tags: php, moodle

I am trying to get a Moodle Course ID in a php script shown below.

I have tested it in different courses and different accounts and it always gives me the ID of 1. Why is that and how to get the correct ID?

```
<?php
require('./config.php');
global $PAGE;

echo $PAGE->course->id;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moodle only knows which course your page is meant to be part of if you tell it (you could have arrived on your page by following a link from any course on the site). When you create a link to your page you need to include a parameter of some kind that will tell your page what course it should be considered part of, e.g. $url = new moodle_url('/blocks/myblock/mypage.php', ['id' => $PAGE->course->id]); echo html_writer($url, 'Look at my page');

Then, once you follow the link, gather the param using required_param() and use require_login() to set up the page. E.g

```
$courseid = required_param('id', PARAM_INT);
$course = $DB->get_record('course', ['id' => $courseid], '*', MUST_EXIST);
require_login($course);
```

After that, $PAGE->course will be configured.

Comment: Thank you, that works fine. But, how can I write that moodle_url inside a block?

Comment: In your block's get_contents() function, simply call new moode_url(...) and then call html_writer::link() and add the result to the $this->contents->text output.

Comment: Is that possible without creating my own block?

Comment: No - I thought that is what you were doing? If you are not creating your own block (are you putting a link in the HTML block?) then the link you use must include the course id as a param.

Comment: Ok, I will work with that. You have helped me a lot. Thank you!